# No such file or directory Ubuntu Commanline

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, files, directory

```
morine_croguennec@MC-Laptop:~$ mkdir TESTgithub
morine_croguennec@MC-Laptop:~$ ls
Bootcamp  TESTgithub  dir1  file1.txt  test_1.
morine_croguennec@MC-Laptop:~$ cd /TESTgithub
-bash: cd: /TESTgithub: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) and I don't know why this happens. As you can see I just made a directory, the ls command shows that I've made it but then when I want to work in it the commandline says it doesn't exist. I'm a noob at commandline so if you could explain this to me that would be really nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current working directory before the $ terminal prompt shows that you are currently in your home directory and so is TESTgithub, however you are trying to change directories with the command `cd /TESTgithub` to it as if it's located in the root directory `/` instead. The correct command to use for this operation is `cd ~/TESTgithub` where the `~` is an abbreviation for your home directory, or you can also use `cd TESTgithub` if you are already in your home directory.